# I want my data to be neatly shown with spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

1. I want to show data neatly formatted with  space between append
2. id one is not selected  i don't know why
3. I want to use append method only because i want to do it dynamically afterwards
4. I want to get data 3 in one columns and another 3 in second  columns

Current output

[image: i am getting output in the following way]

```js
$('#1').append("DARK KNIGHT");
$('#2').append("ACTION");
$('#3').append("NOLEN");
$('#4').append("WB");
$('#5').append("HANSZIMMER");
$('#6').append("WB");
```

```html
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="1" name="id" placeholder="Enter id you want to serch">
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="goodfunction()">Submit</button>

<div class="container">

  <h2>Basic Panel</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-body" id="1">movie</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="2">type</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="3">director</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="4">distributer</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="5">music director</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="6">producer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. It is invalid HTML to have a form in the head

Comment: re: #2 I'm pretty sure you can't have an element ID start with a numeric

Comment: i will correct it

Comment: @dgeare that was true of HTML4, the HTML5 spec removed that restriction

Comment: However neither allows duplicate IDs. Your input field ALSO has ID="1"

Comment: If you want a space, you need to add it: `$('#1').append(" DARK NIGHT");`

Comment: @Mark_M my bad. TIL :-D

Comment: You can use `&nbsp;` In your jQuery string at the start to add a space. It stands for non-breaking space.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a space before the string you are appending (ie " DARK KNIGHT")

2) Your input also has the id "1"

4) You could add a style such as:

```
.panel-body {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}
```

Also, your input and button are in the `<head>` section of your HTML, they should be in the `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a space at the start of the string, you could also do:

```
append("&nbsp;DARK KNIGHT");
```

It's a little clearer in my opinion and not as easy to miss.

`&nbsp;` is a HTML escape for non-breaking space.